# c/c++ - Utilizar sizeof en un archivo

Tags: c++, c

Estoy tratando de responder a la pregunta:

> Si se tiene un archivo declarado "FILE *f;" la funcion sizeof(f) devuelve el tamaño del archivo.

Al cargarle a datos al archivo noto que no se actualiza el tamaño por lo tanto concluyo que es Falso. Aquí el script que usé:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("cagandoejemplos.dat", "wb");

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fwrite(&i,sizeof(int),1,f);
    }

    fclose(f);


    int tam = sizeof(f);
    cout << tam;
    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, buscando en la teoría no puedo dar con una explicació que logre entender porqué size of no estaría funcionando con los archivos. Si puedo ver como ["Calcular la longitud de un fichero"](http://c.conclase.net/ficheros/?cap=004)

Tampoco en encontré la respuesta en el Kernighan y Ritchie. [Qué es la misma que acá](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

Entonces, mi pregunta: si bien no puedo usar 'sizeof' para saber el tamaño de un archivo..¿Por qué es así?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Si se tiene un archivo declarado "FILE *f;" la funcion sizeof(f) devuelve el tamaño del archivo.

Falso, devuelve el tamaño de la variable `f`.

Comment: Solo como aclaracion, del puntero f o del tamaño que ocupa a lo que apunta f?

Comment: El tamaño de `f`. Si quieres saber el tamaño de lo que apunta `f` sería: `sizeof(*f)`

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster aclara que `sizeof` se evalúa en tiempo de compilación, lo que puede dar valores incorrectos en caso de usar polimorfismo

Comment: En realidad sizeof se reemplaza en tiempo de preprocesamiento, no en el de compilación...

Comment: @EduenSarceño ¿preprocesamiento? ¿hablas del preprocesador de macros e includes? No me inspira mucha confianza esa afirmación

Comment: @EduenSarceño por si acaso me explico. El preprocesador se lanza antes de parsear el código, luego el preprocesador no tiene forma de conocer el tamaño de un tipo (mucho menos identificar el tipo a partir de la variable con la que se llama a `sizeof`.

Comment: Error mío, revise el estandar 99 y se especifica que es un operador que dependiendo el tipo se evalua en el tiempo de compilación o bien en tiempo ejecución (ej. con arrays de tamaño arbitrario), desconozco si C++ utiliza tiempo de ejecución al presentarse polimorfismos (debería) y si no lo especifica debería ser un comportamiento de implementación

Comment: @EduenSarceño `sizeof` no es compatible con polimorfismo. En C++ se evalúa **siempre** en tiempo de compilación. Simplificaciones derivadas de usar un tipado más fuerte que en C

Comment: @eferion sí acabo de leer el standar "When applied to an expression, sizeof does not evaluate the expression, and even if the expression designates a polymorphic object, the result is the size of the static type of the expression", gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Si contamos el pre-proceso como una de las fases de la compilación, entonces `sizeof` se evalúa en tiempo de compilación. Lo que está claro que se evalúa al compilar, sea en la fase que sea. `sizeof` está descrito en el 5.3.3 del [estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) y si bien no distingue entre tiempo ejecución/compilación, señala que evalúa expresiones u objetos que dada la naturaleza de C++ se conoce su tipo incluso antes de compilar. `sizeof` de tipos incompletos es ilegal.

Comment: Por otro lado es imposible que `sizeof` se evalúe en el pre-procesado, pues el pre-procesador es una herramienta diferente e independiente del compilador y el pre-procesador es desconocedor de los tipos y la sintaxis del código que evalúa, por lo tanto: si desconoce los tipos consecuencia no puede saber su tamaño.

Answer (score 2):

> Si se tiene un archivo declarado "FILE *f;" la funcion sizeof(f) devuelve el tamaño del archivo.

Esa afirmación, como te ha dicho @PaperBirdMaster, es falsa. `sizeof` es un operador que indica el tamaño que ocupa el *tipo* que se le pasa como parámetro.

En el caso que nos ocupa, `f` no es más que un puntero a una estructura usada a nivel interno por la librería de entrada/salida para gestionar el acceso a un archivo. Dicho de otra forma... **no tienes acceso directo al fichero**, luego no puedes usar `sizeof` para resolver el problema.

> Si puedo ver como "Calcular la longitud de un fichero"

Yo no me fiaría de esas respuestas por varios motivos:

- Si el fichero es binario `fseek(SEEK_END)` no es seguro. Los sistemas tienen la mala costumbre de paginar y segmentar la memoria. Esto hace que un fichero que ocupe un solo bit ocupe hasta varios KB en el disco (depende del sistema de archivos utilizado)... que viene a ser el tamaño de un bloque. El acceso binario en estos casos puede ser incapaz de detectar el final del fichero ya que, al fin y al cabo, todo son bytes y todos pueden ser válidos.

  De hecho en la [documentación](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) se puede leer el siguiente aviso:

  > Binary streams are not required to support SEEK_END, in particular if additional null bytes are output.
- Si el fichero es de texto y no usa codificación ASCII habrá caracteres que ocupan más de 1 byte... en este caso irse al final del fichero y medir el offset va a dar un resultado incorrecto... te va a decir que el fichero es más largo.

  Nuevamente en la documentación se puede leer lo siguiente:

  > If the stream is wide-oriented, the restrictions of both text and binary streams apply (result of ftell is allowed with SEEK_SET and zero offset is allowed from SEEK_SET and SEEK_CUR, but not SEEK_END).

Así que lo siento. El ejemplo que has elegido te va a dar problemas por todos lados.

¿Entonces?

Lamentablemente no hay una solución estándar. Si partes del supuesto de que el fichero contiene texto ASCII entonces sí que podrías hacer uso del ejemplo que comentas... pero conociendo siempre sus limitaciones.

Otra opción podría pasar por abrir el fichero con *wide chars* para adaptarse a la codificación que esté usando el fichero y leer caracter a caracter llevando la cuenta (es un mecanismo lento pero con ficheros pequeños podría valer).

Una tercera posibilidad (si solo te interesa saber el tamaño aproximado) es acceder a las propiedades del fichero:

```
size_t TamFichero(std::string const& nombre)
{
  stat stat_buf;
  int rc = stat(nombre.c_str(), &stat_buf);
  if (rc == 0)
    return stat_buf.st_size;
  return -1;
}
```